# Wordpress: 505 error on post.php

Tags: wordpress, web

I have a problem with my Wordpress site. When I try to edit old pages/post - I get "500 Internal Server Error". If I create a new page/post and edit it - it works fine.

I tried all the options I could find on Google:

1. Switched off all of the plugins.
2. Changed main Theme.
3. Created new clean .htaccess
4. Tried "debug mode' in Wp-Config
5. Checked all the rights to folders or files (all 755 or 644)
6. Increased memory in Wp-Confid to '64M' and '256M'
7. Contacted the host (they said we don't know, the problem is on your side)
8. Changed PHP to Apache from CGI(Apache).

Nothing helped.

What I get from Log:

> [Tue Jun 27 02:02:37.218178 2017] [core:error] [pid 28851] [client 138.246.253.30:60354] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
>
> [Tue Jun 27 02:02:37.309418 2017] [core:error] [pid 27769] [client 138.246.253.30:60356] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.'

What else can I try?

Comment: Can you send your code here? You may have miss writen something or forgot end tags somewhere?

Comment: @J.Rajamäki You mean the post.php? It is generated automatically by wordpress, its pretty big, I'm not sure it is possible to post it here. However I replaced it with new clean one and problem stayed, so probably the problem is not in post.php file.

Comment: You can send the part that you have modified if you have done so?

Comment: @J.Rajamäki The thing is I did not modify any part of it. The file is the same as on Wordpress.org repository.

Comment: There is nothing i could have done then, sorry.

Comment: Try to configure and check that website at your local server or pc,

Comment: Please increase memory all the way to 256M and go to phpmysql and repair your database. If this doesn't fix, I guarantee it is php module that is misconfigured. To find out go to your plesk or cpanel or whatever panel you have and switch from Fast CGI to Apache or other available module.

Comment: @MrJackMcfreder Increased memory to 256M, repaired database and changed to Apache, didn't help( Added log of errors to question.

Comment: That error seems to be related to .htaccess file. It's an infinite loop. Just a question, is your wordpress installation installed in a directory? if that so make sure to include the base path. Here is a pastebin for a more info how your htaccess should look like: https://pastebin.com/uUmVCnva

Comment: And this post might be helpful as well: http://willcodeforcoffee.com/2007/01/31/cakephp-error-500-too-many-redirects/

Comment: @MrJackMcfreder I thought so too in the beginning and I deleted my old htaccess and made new clean one. Unfortunately that didn't help.